# How to undo a git commit --amend

Tags: git

I accidentally typed in a git commit --amend. This is a mistake because I realized that the commit is actually entirely new and it should be committed with a new message. I want to make a new commit. How do I undo this?

Comment: `git reset --soft @{1}`

Comment: `git reset --soft @{1}` doesn't work for me. I just revert the commit, then squash them. solved this problem.

Comment: The repeat of this question led to even better information, just saying

Answer (score 162, accepted):

[PetSerAl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001038/how-to-undo-a-git-commit-amend#comment63446333_38001038) is the key.  Here's the two command sequence to do just what you want:

```
git reset --soft @{1}
git commit -C @{1}
```

and an explanation of how this works.

#### Description

When you make a new commit, Git usually<sup>1</sup> uses this sequence of events:

1. Read the ID (SHA-1 hash, like `a123456...`) of the current commit (via `HEAD`, which gives us the current branch).  Let's call this ID *C* (for Current).  Note that this current commit has a parent commit; let's call its ID *P* (for Parent).
2. Turn the index (aka staging-area) into a tree.  This produces another ID; let's call this ID *T* (for Tree).
3. Write a new commit with parent = *C* and tree = *T*.  This new commit gets another ID.  Let's call this *N* (for New).
4. Update the branch with the new commit ID *N*.

When using `--amend` Git changes the process a bit.  It still writes a new commit as before, but in step 3, instead of writing the new commit with parent = *C*, it writes it with parent = *P*.

#### Picture

Pictorially, we can draw what happened this way.  We start with a commit graph that ends in `P--C`, pointed-to by `branch`:

```
...--P--C   <-- branch
```

When we make the new commit `N` we get:

```
...--P--C--N   <-- branch
```

When we use `--amend`, we get this instead:

```
       C
      /
...--P--N   <-- branch
```

Note that commit `C` is *still in the repository*; it's just been shoved aside, up out of the way, so that new commit `N` can point back to old parent `P`.

#### Goal

What you realized you *want*, after the `git commit --amend`, is to have the chain look instead like:

```
...--P--C--N   <-- branch
```

We can't *quite* do this—we can't change `N`; Git can never change *any* commit (or any other object) once it's stored in the repo—but note that the `...--P--C` chain is still in there, fully intact.  You can find commit `C` through the reflogs, and this is what the `@{1}` syntax does.  (Specifically, this is short for `currentbranch@{1}`,<sup>2</sup> which means "where *`currentbranch`* pointed one step ago", which was "to commit `C`".)

So, we now run `git reset --soft @{1}`, which does this:

```
       C   <-- branch
      /
...--P--N
```

Now `branch` points to `C`, which points back to `P`.

What happens to `N`?  The same thing that happened to `C` before: it's saved for a while through the reflog.

We don't really need it (although it may come in handy), because the `--soft` flag to `git reset` keeps the index / staging-area untouched (along with the work-tree).  This means we can make a new commit again now, by just running another `git commit`.  It will go through the same four steps (read the ID from `HEAD`, create the tree, create a new commit, and update the branch):

```
       C--N2   <-- branch
      /
...--P--N
```

where `N2` will be our new new (second new?) commit.

We can even make `git commit` re-use the commit message from commit `N`.  The `git commit` command has a `--reuse-message` argument, also spelled `-C`; all we have to do is give it something that lets it find the original new commit `N` from which to copy the message, to make `N2` with.  How do we do that?  The answer is: it's in the reflog, just as `C` was when we needed to do the `git reset`.

In fact, it's the same `@{1}`!

Remember, `@{1}` means "where it was just a moment ago", and `git reset` just updated it, moving it from `C` to `N`.  We haven't yet *made* new commit `N2`.  (Once we do that, `N` will be `@{2}`, but we haven't yet.)

So, putting it all together, we get:

```
git reset --soft @{1}
git commit -C @{1}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>The places this description breaks down include when you're amending a merge, when you're on a detached HEAD, and when you use an alternative index.  Even then, though, it's pretty obvious how to modify the description.

<sup>2</sup>If `HEAD` is detached, so that there *is* no current branch, the meaning becomes `HEAD@{1}`.  Note that `@` by itself is short for `HEAD`, so the fact that `@{n}` refers to the current branch, rather than to `HEAD` itself, is a bit inconsistent.

To see how they differ, consider `git checkout develop` followed by `git checkout master` (assuming both branches exist).  The first `checkout` changes `HEAD` to point to `develop`, and the second changes `HEAD` to point to `master`.  This means that `master@{1}` is whatever commit `master` pointed to, before the last update to `master`; but `HEAD@{1}` is the commit `develop` points to now—probably some other commit.

(Recap: after these two `git checkout` commands, `@{1}` means `master@{1}` now, `HEAD@{1}` means the same commit as `develop` now, and `@` means `HEAD`.  If you're confused, well, so was I, and apparently I am not alone: see the comments.)

Comment: AFAIK, `@{1}` is short for `currentbranch@{1}` not `HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Aha, you're right!  Though if HEAD is detached it works as `HEAD@{1}`.  This seems a bit inconsistent since `@` means `HEAD`, but I suppose `HEAD@{0}` and `currentbranch@{0}` are necessarily synonymous, if there is a current branch at all.  Thanks, I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @andrybak: test it out by moving `HEAD`  and/or some branches a few times, detaching HEAD, moving it some more, and reattaching it.  The semantics are more convoluted than the syntax.

Comment: @andrybak Even so `HEAD` is symbolic ref, `@{1}` and `@@{1}` have different meaning.

Comment: A very good explanation

Comment: Didn't work for me. Commands had zero effect.

Comment: @8bitjunkie: Don't just blindly use `@{1}` because if you've done anything *since* the `git commit --amend`, it won't be `1` any more. Run `git reflog` if needed, to find the right hash ID or number for the `@{...}` syntax.

Comment: Thanks @torek that must have been what happened in my case.

Comment: Please note that for some command shells you may need to wrap @{1} in quotes "@{1}"